# equivalent of select for pipes on windows

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe

I need to block until one of my pipes has data to be read.

I have tried WaitForMultipleObjects but it just returns immediately saying that one of the pipes has data. A subsequent ReadFile on the pipe blocks.

I cannot use PeekNamedPipe because I need to block until data is available, and peeking in a loop with sleep would result in a delayed reaction because of the sleep.

This code is cross-platform and everything works great on linux because I can use Select on a set of fifo fd's and then read from the one that is ready when select returns, however there doesn't seem to be any equivalent on windows.

I have seen many people saying you have to use overlapped operations with read/writes, but wouldn't this then require me to loop and try and read every single pipe?

Is there no single blocking operation that will block till one of the pipes has data in it?

Comment: "I have tried WaitForMultipleObjects" - if you think the code you've written in attempt to solve your problem is relevant, you're right. It belongs in the question, stripped down to as minimal, yet ideally complete, example as posible that reproduces your problem. For all we know you're using WaitForMultipleObjects incorrectly, and no code has been posted to refute that assumption. And yes, overlapped or iocp is how I would probably do this.

Comment: @EJP Good god! Isn't 1993 before the invention of fire?

Comment: On a more serious note: `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + n` where `n` is the index of the array index signaled.  My guess since that's clearly spelled out in the documentation, is that you aren't actually checking the return value, and the call to `WaitForSingleObject` is actually returning `WAIT_FAILED`. (Of course this is what's known in the business as an educated guess, since you don't show us what you're actually doing. You may have written code that does check the return value correctly, and handles errors brilliantly.)

Comment: I can't post code now because it is at work and I am home now, for the record though I was indeed handling the return value correctly because that's how I determined which handle was being signaled.

The issue is that WaitForMultipleObjects is returning immediately, when there is nothing in the pipe.

MSDN states: "Note that WAIT_OBJECT_0 is defined as 0".  

The code that was being executed afterward was the result of (rv - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 0, so from what I saw it was signaling me that the 0th handle was ready - then a subsequent ReadFile blocked.

Comment: If you read the documentation for `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, a pipe is not a supported object type for it to wait on. Make sure the return value is actually in the range of `WAIT_OBJECT_0` - `WAIT_OBJECT_0+n` before subtracting `WAIT_OBJECT_0` to get the index.

Comment: If you use sockets rather than pipes, you can have a single implementation (using select(), if you like) that works the same way on all OS's.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I might be doing that eventually, might make things a lot simpler all around

Comment: Correction. I think I associated a semaphore with the pipe and used a semaphore wait API, can't remember which one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have tried WaitForMultipleObjects but it just returns immediately saying that one of the pipes has data. A subsequent ReadFile on the pipe blocks.

Pipes are not mentioned in MSDN's list of waitable object types, so you can't pass a pipe to any of the `WaitFor...()` family of functions.

> I have seen many people saying you have to use overlapped operations with read/writes, but wouldn't this then require me to loop and try and read every single pipe?

Overlapped I/O is the solution to your problem.

Create your pipes in overlapped mode.  Then you can either:

1. create an event object via `CreateEvent()` and assign it to the `OVERLAPPED` structure you use for a given read operation.  Then you can issue asynchronous `ReadFile/Ex()` operations on multiple pipes and use `WaitForMultipleObject()` to wait on the event objects until one of them is signaled.  The return value of `WaitForMultipleObjects()` will tell you which event was signaled, and by association which pipe has read some data.
2. use `GetQueuedCompletionStatus/Ex()` instead of `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, then you can omit the event objects.  `GetQueuedCompletionStatus/Ex()` will tell you which specific `OVERLAPPED` struct(s) have been completed (you can use the `hEvent` field to pass around user-defined data, if desired).

This is covered in the MSDN documentation:

[Synchronous and Overlapped Pipe I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365788.aspx)

`select()` can report multiple completed operations in a single call.  However, `WaitForMultipleObjects()` and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` can only report a single completed operation at a time.  You would have to call them in a loop to discover if multiple operations have completed.  `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx()`, on the other hand, can report multiple completed operations at one time.

> Is there no single blocking operation that will block till one of the pipes has data in it?

Yes.  See above.

Comment: Wonderful, much better than the comments that said I could  be dealing with the return value of WaitForMultipleObjects wrong. This is definitely going to be a pain because I had originally wrapped POSIX and windows pipes and didn't provide any method of using overlapping. I'm going to have to go back and change lots in order to make this work.  
Thank you again though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using overlapped I/O is the best choice. You can bind every pipe handle to an I/O Completion Port (directly via `CreateIoCompletionPort()`, or indirectly via `BindIoCompletionCallback()`).  For asynchronous reading, create a struct inherited from `OVERLAPPED` and pass it to `ReadFile/Ex()` with a pipe handle.  Each read needs its own allocated instance of that struct.  Then you can use `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` (or the bound callback) to detect when each read has been completed. You do not need any loops.

Comment: I tried to fix the grammar here, but the last 'sentence' makes no sense. If you're going to answer, especially questions like this one, please proofread your answer before you submit it. (On a question like this one, and in the WinAPI tag in general, you don't have to be the fastest gun in the west, as long as you proofread your answer and be reasonably complete.)