# Equivalent of select or poll for pipes on Windows

Tags: c, winapi, pipe

Some Unix code I am working on depends on being able to `poll` over a small number of pipes. [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html) is a POSIX system call that (much like the older [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/select.html)) allows the process to wait until one or more file descriptors is "ready" for reading or writing, which means one can proceed to do so without blocking. This is useful to implement event loops where waiting is clearly separated from the rest of the communication.

Is it possible to do the same for Windows pipe handles - wait for one or more of them to become "ready" for reading/writing?

Existing SO advice on the matter, such as answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277148/equivalent-of-select-for-pipes-on-windows), recommend the use of completion ports. However as far as I can tell, completion ports require *initiating* reading/writing beforehand, and then waiting for (or being notified of) the completion of those operations. This approach does not fit the architecture of the code, which strongly separates the polling code from the reading/writing code, the latter calling into a library that uses the regular `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` on the underlying handle.

If there is no direct equivalent to `poll`, could one abuse completion ports to provide something similar? In other words, is it possible to create IO completion events that announce "you can now call `ReadFile` (`WriteFile`) on this handle without it blocking" and wait for them using `WaitForMultipleObjects` or `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`?

Comment: with `IOCP` all operations on pipe handle is asynchronous - return without blocking. several threads in working pool wait for operation completed and call your callback on pipe. usually all this job windows can do internal for you (create `IOCP`, thread pool, wait on events) but however you can and direct create own `IOCP` and own pool, direct wait by `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`..

Comment: @RbMm That much is clear. The question is can I use IOCP to implement the equivalent of `poll`, i.e. to get the information "you can now issue a read/write of this file handle which won't block"? Even with a manually created IOCP and thread pool, it is not clear how to e.g. wait for data to become available for read without also reading them.

Comment: I nothing can say about `poll` logic, but with `IOCP` all is very clear. you call read just after connect, and next time call read, after previous finished. until disconnect

Comment: What about ReadFile with a 0-sized buffer?

Comment: @conio Good suggestion, I think I'll try that.

Comment: @RbMm What do you mean by "call read just after connect"? My understanding of IOCP is that one can request e.g. asynchronous reading of data, and it would both read the data for me, and notify me that it's finished. If you are saying that it is also possible to be notified of data *availability*, please elaborate.

Comment: "call read just after connect"?  - from server side - this when `ConnectNamedPipe` finished (`FSCTL_PIPE_LISTEN` request). from client side connect always synchronous (`CreateFile` or `ZwOpenFile`). after this we can begin read data. simply call `ReadFile` which always just return control. when we got notify that `ReadFile` finished - after process data - new call to `ReadFile` and so on. until disconnect. but this is not notify about data *availability* - this is actual data reading. so we begin read and got notify when read finished. but not got notify when data exist

Comment: why you what got notify about some data available but without  got this data ?

Comment: To poll for available data without actually reading it, use `PeekNamedPipe()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `PeekNamedPipe` allows checking for data availability, but not waiting for it to become available. Also, it doesn't work for writing.

Comment: @RbMm Because I am dealing with an architecture that already has a portable IO layer that wraps native file descriptors (on Unix) or native file handles (on Windows). On Unix, this is easy to combine with a `select` or `poll` based event loop. For porting such code, a `poll` like functionality for Windows file handles would come in extremely useful.

Comment: It's worth trying zero-byte reads and writes as conio suggests (though you should note that a zero-byte write is not a no-op, the other end of the pipe will see it) but you may need to add support for polling into the I/O layer, so that you can emulate it with async I/O.  (Arguably that's where it belongs anyway; it is an I/O operation after all.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Unfortunately the IO layer is written separately from the polling layer, and with blocking operations in mind. (Think of something like stdio, but with buffering optional.) This is why I am investigating the equivalent of `poll`, which works with both blocking and non-blocking sockets, and is separated from the actual IO — something like `WSASelect` that works for pipes. The current Windows port uses a simple thread-per-pipe model to ensure deadlock-free communication. This works (the number of pipes is very small), but I'd prefer to eliminate the overhead of thread creation.

Comment: Afaik issueing 0byte IOCP reads for querying for available data works. Although I don't know about whether this works for pipes and for the writing site too. There's also `WSAEventSelect`, but I guess that only works for sockets and not pipes.

Comment: There is also `WSAPoll()`, but that is only for sockets. There simply is no direct equivalent of `select()`/`poll()` for pipes on Windows. Other than `PeekNamedPipe()`, you can use Overlapped IO or IOCP to start an async read/write, then wait for the completion event with a timeout, and if that elapses than optionally use `CancelIo/Ex()` if needed.

Comment: *Unfortunately the IO layer is written separately from the polling layer, and with blocking operations in mind* - that shouldn't be an insurmountable barrier, unless you mean you're simply not allowed to make changes to the IO layer?  In that case, asynchronous I/O won't work anyway, since the IO layer presumably expects to be dealing with a synchronous handle.

Comment: For what it's worth, though, the overhead of having a small number of extra threads is negligible.  You should perhaps implement a thread pool so that you're not constantly creating and destroying them, but other than that it probably isn't worth the trouble that would be involved in redesigning the IO layer, even if that was an option.